# Opengl nvidia gpu multisampling

Tags: java, opengl

I have a 3d program that was working fine before I updated my nvidia gf 620m graphics drivers to version 22.21.13.8494 .Now whenever I run the program I get a black screen . I tried to find the source of the problem and it seems to be with the multisampling FBO in my program as the problem only occurs when its enabled.

My FBO class.

```
public class Fbo {

    public static final int NONE = 0;
    public static final int DEPTH_TEXTURE = 1;
    public static final int DEPTH_RENDER_BUFFER = 2;

    private final int width;
    private final int height;

    private int frameBuffer;

    private boolean multisampleMultiTargets = false;

    private int colourTexture;
    private int depthTexture;

    private int depthBuffer;
    private int colourBuffer;
    private int colourBuffer2;

    /**
     * Creates an FBO of a specified width and height, with the desired type of
     * depth buffer attachment.
     * 
     * @param width
     *            - the width of the FBO.
     * @param height
     *            - the height of the FBO.
     * @param depthBufferType
     *            - an int indicating the type of depth buffer attachment that
     *            this FBO should use.
     */
    public Fbo(int width, int height, int depthBufferType) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        initialiseFrameBuffer(depthBufferType);
    }

    public Fbo(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.multisampleMultiTargets = true;
        initialiseFrameBuffer(DEPTH_RENDER_BUFFER);
    }


    /**
     * Deletes the frame buffer and its attachments when the game closes.
     */
    public void cleanUp() {
        GL30.glDeleteFramebuffers(frameBuffer);
        GL11.glDeleteTextures(colourTexture);
        GL11.glDeleteTextures(depthTexture);
        GL30.glDeleteRenderbuffers(depthBuffer);
        GL30.glDeleteRenderbuffers(colourBuffer);
        GL30.glDeleteRenderbuffers(colourBuffer2);
    }

    /**
     * Binds the frame buffer, setting it as the current render target. Anything
     * rendered after this will be rendered to this FBO, and not to the screen.
     */
    public void bindFrameBuffer() {

        GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
        GL11.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    /**
     * Unbinds the frame buffer, setting the default frame buffer as the current
     * render target. Anything rendered after this will be rendered to the
     * screen, and not this FBO.
     */
    public void unbindFrameBuffer() {
        GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        GL11.glViewport(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
    }

    /**
     * Binds the current FBO to be read from (not used in tutorial 43).
     */
    public void bindToRead() {
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
        GL11.glReadBuffer(GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    }

    /**
     * @return The ID of the texture containing the colour buffer of the FBO.
     */
    public int getColourTexture() {
        return colourTexture;
    }

    /**
     * @return The texture containing the FBOs depth buffer.
     */
    public int getDepthTexture() {
        return depthTexture;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the FBO along with a colour buffer texture attachment, and
     * possibly a depth buffer.
     * 
     * @param type
     *            - the type of depth buffer attachment to be attached to the
     *            FBO.
     */
    public void resolveToFbo(int readBuffer,Fbo outputFbo){
        GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,outputFbo.frameBuffer);
        GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER,this.frameBuffer);
        GL11.glReadBuffer(readBuffer);
        GL30.glBlitFramebuffer(0,0,width,height,0,0,outputFbo.width,outputFbo.height,GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT,GL11.GL_LINEAR);
        this.unbindFrameBuffer();
    }
    public void resolveToScreen(){
        GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,0);
        GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER,this.frameBuffer);
        GL11.glDrawBuffer(GL11.GL_BACK);
        GL30.glBlitFramebuffer(0,0,width,height,0,0,Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight(),GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT ,GL11.GL_LINEAR);
        this.unbindFrameBuffer();
    }

    private void initialiseFrameBuffer(int type) {
        createFrameBuffer();
        if(multisampleMultiTargets){
            colourBuffer = createMultisampledColourbuffer(GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
            colourBuffer2 = createMultisampledColourbuffer(GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
        }else{
        createTextureAttachment();
        }
        if (type == DEPTH_RENDER_BUFFER) {
            createDepthBufferAttachment();
        } else if (type == DEPTH_TEXTURE) {
            createDepthTextureAttachment();
        }
        unbindFrameBuffer();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new frame buffer object and sets the buffer to which drawing
     * will occur - colour attachment 0. This is the attachment where the colour
     * buffer texture is.
     * 
     */
    private void createFrameBuffer() {
        frameBuffer = GL30.glGenFramebuffers();
        GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
        determineDrawBuffer();
    }

    private void determineDrawBuffer(){
        IntBuffer drawBuffers = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(2);
        drawBuffers.put(GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
        if(this.multisampleMultiTargets){
            drawBuffers.put(GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
        }
        drawBuffers.flip();
        GL20.glDrawBuffers(drawBuffers);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a texture and sets it as the colour buffer attachment for this
     * FBO.
     */
    private void createTextureAttachment() {
        colourTexture = GL11.glGenTextures();
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, colourTexture);
        GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                (ByteBuffer) null);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GL30.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, colourTexture,
                0);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a depth buffer to the FBO in the form of a texture, which can later
     * be sampled.
     */
    private void createDepthTextureAttachment() {
        depthTexture = GL11.glGenTextures();
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
        GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL14.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, width, height, 0, GL11.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,
                GL11.GL_FLOAT, (ByteBuffer) null);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
        GL30.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL30.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture, 0);
    }

    private int createMultisampledColourbuffer(int Attachment){
        int colourBuffer =  GL30.glGenRenderbuffers();
        GL30.glBindRenderbuffer(GL30.GL_RENDERBUFFER, colourBuffer);
        GL30.glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL30.GL_RENDERBUFFER,4, GL11.GL_RGBA8, width, height);
        GL30.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER,Attachment, GL30.GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                colourBuffer);

        return colourBuffer;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a depth buffer to the FBO in the form of a render buffer. This can't
     * be used for sampling in the shaders.
     */
    private void createDepthBufferAttachment() {
        depthBuffer = GL30.glGenRenderbuffers();
        GL30.glBindRenderbuffer(GL30.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);
        if(!multisampleMultiTargets){
        GL30.glRenderbufferStorage(GL30.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL14.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, width, height);
        }else{
            GL30.glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL30.GL_RENDERBUFFER,4, GL14.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, width, height);
        }
        GL30.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL30.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL30.GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                depthBuffer);
    }

}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Its in java progrqmming language

Comment: Gl30.glcheckFramebufferStatus returns True .

Comment: The Frame Buffer is complete

Comment: Try to go in NVDIA control panel and see if multi sampling is enabled and if not try to enable it for all applications and then run your sample.

Comment: Thats what I first did but it did, not work. I messed around with every single setting on the nvidia control panel with no success.

Comment: The only thing that stands out in the code shown is that your colour buffer implementation depends on whether or not multi-sampling is enabled -- render buffers if enabled, textures if not.  Not sure if that's significant without seeing more code.

Comment: The other significant piece of code is in the, game renderer . Fbo multisampleFbo = new Fbo(Display. Getwidth(),Display. Getheight(),Fbo. DEPTH_RENDER_BUFFER);       Fbo output1 = new Fbo(Display. Getwidth(),Display. Getheight(),Fbo. DEPTH_TEXTURE);

Comment: I then bind the frame, buffer before rendering the scene  multisampleFbo. BindFrameBuffer ();            render();                             multisampleFbo .unbindFrameBuffer();           multisampleFbo .resolveToFbo(GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,output1);        PostProcessing. DoPostProcessing(output1.getColorTexture());   . Thats it for the code.

Comment: The statement `DoPostProcessing(output1.getColorTexture());` looks suspicious.  From the code posted `getColourTexture` returns the `colourTexture` member which, if multi-sampling is enabled, appears to be uninitialized.

Comment: So how should I fix it . Any help will be appreciated